# Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9]

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

I understand why I am getting this error. My question is more: How can I solve it?

The problem is: I am creating an Android Icon Pack and the Youtube activity name happens to include a '$'. I cannot theme this app unless I include the $ in the filename (as far as I know). I have tried to replace it with an '_' and it does not work.

Comment: $ is a separator for an inner class.  That is how you reference inner classes inside the Manifest or in layout files.

Answer (score 3):

File name must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or _.

- only `a-z`,mind that not capital...and `white-space not allowed`
- name must start with a character.not with a Number(0-9)
- name only `_` symbol allowed.no other symbol alowed.